# How does $H=U+PV$ come up when its definition never talks about such equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

For first law of thermodynamics, what the law states can be matched with the equation, U=q+W
, could anyone provide me insight on how does H=U+PV
equation comes up? What is the physical meaning of H ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H=U+PV$ is not a law but more a definition of the quantity $H$ as being the enthalpy. So unlinke $\Delta U=Q+W$ it is not associated to a law at the foundation of thermodynamics stating something deep about heat exchanges. However $H$ reveal itself to be a very useful state function when studying heat transfers.

Comment: if H is defined as U+PV why is it sometimes also said that it measures energy of reaction etc, and why is it defined the way it is? Does it carry and physical meaning?

Comment: Good question! A possible way to answer (though quite abstract) is that $H$ is a so-called "thermodynamical potential" and in a sense it plays a role similar to the potential functions $V$ in point mechanics, as it drives the time evolution of the systems towards its minimum or maximum. In that case $H$ can be interpreted as "the capacity to do non-mechanical work plus the capacity to release heat." and its variation " $\Delta H $ is the sum of non-mechanical work done on the system and the heat given to it." (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential)

Comment: $H$ is especially interesting to study systems at constant pressure. Again from the wikipedia page above "When the pressure p and external parameters of a closed system are held constant, the enthalpy H decreases and reaches a minimum value at equilibrium."

Comment: Then, studing how $H$ evolves with time tells you how the systems evolve. It should decrease until a minimum and observing its non variation is a signature of equilibrium (for the special case of closed system and constant pressure which is commonly assumed for experiments done on earth's surface at atmospheric pressure)

Comment: just a doubt, so H doesent carry much meaning under non constant pressure systems?

Comment: It seems that it looses a lot of its utility and meaningfulness in that case indeed. I am however honestly not expert enough to know if there are special cases in which $H$ could keep a deep meaning with a non constant pressure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: My pleasure! Maybe someone else here will have some nice complements to add ;)

Comment: H is a state variable/TD potential  in any case. But at constant pressure, it has effectively meaning of "isobaric internal energy", where part of energy is effectively "stored in/released from an external storage" as the system volume work W = -p. Delta V.